# YADCF, column visibility doesn't work properly with filter_container_id

Tags: jquery, datatable, yadcf

I've a little issue with Datatables, YADCF and Button Colvis :
I can't use in the same table the property visible:false, a filter_container_id and yadcf. The yadcf plugin crash and not display anything. This is an cleaned-up version of my datatable initialisation :

```
datatable = $('#Datatable').DataTable({
    serverSide:true,
    processing:true,
    ajax: {
        url: '/app/object/liste',
        type: "POST"
    },
    columns: [
        {data:"pc_id", width:"90px"},
        {data:"pc_statut", visible:false, width:"90px"},
        {data:"reference_dossier", width:"90px"}],
    buttons: [{
        extend: 'colvis',
        text: 'Colonnes',
        collectionLayout: 'fixed three-column',
        columns: ':gt(0)'
    }],
    initComplete:function(a, b){
        new $.fn.dataTable.FixedColumns(datatable, {
            leftColumns: 1
        });

        var clonedTable = document.querySelectorAll('.DTFC_Cloned');
        for (var i = 0; i < clonedTable.length; i++){
            clonedTable[i].id = 'DTFC_Cloned';
        }
        $('#DTFC_Cloned thead tr:eq(1) th:last-child').append(
            '<span id="fixed_col_filter_container"></span>'
        );

        yadcf.init(
            datatable,
            [
                {
                    column_number:1,
                    filter_container_id:"fixed_col_filter_container",
                    filter_type:"text",
                    filter_delay:"500"
                },{
                    column_number:2,
                    filter_container_id:"pc-pc_statut-2",
                    filter_type:"text",
                    filter_delay:"500"
                },{
                    column_number:3,
                    filter_container_id:"pc-reference_dossier-2",
                    filter_type:"text",
                    filter_delay:"500"
                }
            ],
            {language: tabLanguage}
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: yadcf doesn't play well with  FixedColumns, try to see how it works without it and try to move the yadcf init out of the initComplete, if still dont work - provide a link to a test case

Comment: Sorry, this one is better : http://live.datatables.net/betupena/2/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a fix to yadcf and fixed your code as well,

Grab the latest [0.9.0.beta.23](https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/blob/7839bfbf2be5d93624660acbf28d90489091062d/jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js) and note that **`column_number` values are zero based** (first column should have `column_number: 0` and so on)

[See it working here](http://live.datatables.net/betupena/3/edit)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the commit !!! I've grab the latest version, and yadcf do the job. One more question : how coul'd I add a class to a range date filter (or range number) width button colvis (without, it's easy with a few lines of JS but not with colvis...) ? I've seen the option style_class to the other filters. For bootstrap integration, I need to add input-group on the wrapper and form-control / input-sm class on inputs.

Comment: if my answer solved you question, mark it as accepted, as to the style... best thing is to send a PR just like someone did a few days ago, [see this PR](https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/pull/337) because I wont be able to do it in the near future